# PHP Fatal error: "The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action"

Tags: php, soap

I'm attempting to write a PHP script that will connect to the SOAP client for our SightMax interface.  With the code below I am able to print out a list of functions available however when I try and call any function I am getting the the following error.

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient('http://domain.com/SightMaxWebServices/SightMaxWebService.svc?wsdl', array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));

var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

$result = $client->__call("GetSiteSummary", array());

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

---

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [s:Sender] The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'SmartMax.SightMax.Agent.Operator/IRemotedWebsiteAdministrator/GetSiteSummary'. in test2.php:7 Stack trace: #0 test2.php(7): SoapClient->__call('GetSiteSummary', Array) #1 {main} thrown in test2.php on line 7
```

I've been researching this error for the last couple days and I've read different articles stating possible issues.  From what I understand this error occurs because the SOAP client is configured for wsHttpBinding and either the build in SOAP client for PHP does not support the wsHttpBinding or I need to specifically specify the SOAP action.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?  Please keep in mind while I'm versed with PHP working with SOAP is new to me so step by steps are very helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hev you tried omitting the version parameter in `new SoapClient`? Soap 1.2 does not use the SOAP action header, 1.1 does. It might be, that the server only understands 1.1?

Comment: When I remove the SOAP_1_2 version parameter I get a different error

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'. in test2.php:5 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('GetSiteSummary', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/tools/html/whoseonchat/test2.php on line 5

Answer (score 19):

WCF seems to be looking for the action in the SOAP envelope.  You can add it to your call with PHP's SoapClient this way:

```
$actionHeader = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing',
                               'Action',
                               'http://soapaction.that.was.in.the.wsdl');
$client->__setSoapHeaders($actionHeader);
```

If you change the third parameter and add that between your instantiation of $client and the __call() it should clear the error (and possibly bring on new ones, isn't SOAP fun?)

Also FYI, having just gone through this same problem, I found the __getLastRequestHeaders(), __getLastRequest(), __getLastResponseHeaders(), and __getLastResponse() functions very handy to see if what I was trying had any effect (note that you need to add "trace" => "1" to your SoapClient options for those to work.)

Comment: This works great.

If you can't find the Action, it is in the wsdl with the following attribute:
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="[the-action-you-want]" message="[some-value-too]"/>

Comment: This answer saved my day! Also, this answer was very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32641267/1795351

Answer (score 1):

You should give the SOAP Action. Since you do not include it in the initialization of `SoapClient`, it doesn't match the SOAP Action of the web service. Make sure you know what the SOAP Action is before connecting.

Read http://www.oreillynet.com/xml/blog/2002/11/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html for more on the subject.

Comment: I've read through the article and I still don't understand.  How can I explicitly state the SOAP action in my script?

Comment: I don't know that, I just told you that you should let know what the SOAP Action should be. I'm sorry.