# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Bad Request

Tags: php, soap

I'm attempting to write a PHP script that will connect to the SOAP client for our SightMax interface.  With the code below I am getting the the following error.

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://domain.com/SightMaxWebServices/SightMaxWebService.svc?wsdl', array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_2));

$result = $client->__soapCall("GetSiteSummary", array(), array(), new soapHeader('action','SmartMax.SightMax.Agent.Operator/IRemotedWebsiteAdministrator/CreateCallQueue'));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Bad Request in test2.php:5 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__soapCall('GetSiteSummary', Array, Array, Object(SoapHeader)) #2 {main} thrown in test2.php on line 5
```

This is a continuance of [PHP Fatal error: "The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934365/php-fatal-error-the-soap-action-specified-on-the-message-does-not-match-t) where I wasn't specifying the SOAP Action header.  I believe I am specifying the header now but alas a new error.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the version of soap, also you can try $client->__getTypes to see what structure is specting your WS.

I have similar problem with my request:
[how to generate a soap request in php from this xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10490497/1102049)