# how to generate a soap request in php from this xml?

Tags: php, xml, soap, request

I'm tired of trying to send a request with SOAP. this is my xml

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:bpf="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Bpf.Security.Common" xmlns:bpf1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Bpf.Security.Authentication.Common">
         <soapenv:Header>
 <InfoTag xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/BaufestProductivityFramework">
  <ClientIp xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Bpf.Common.Service">200.125.145.10</ClientIp> 
  <CompanyId xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Bpf.Common.Service">1</CompanyId>
  <UserName xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Bpf.Common.Service">someUser</UserName> 
  </InfoTag>
        </soapenv:Header>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <tem:LogIn>         
                <tem:token>
                    <bpf:type>
                       <bpf1:Description>someDesc</bpf1:Description>
                       <bpf1:Id>1</bpf1:Id>
                       <bpf1:Name>someDesc</bpf1:Name>
                    </bpf:type>
                    <bpf:password>somePass</bpf:password>
                    <bpf:userName>someUser</bpf:userName>
                </tem:token>
              </tem:LogIn>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

this function send the header with a namespace, but there are more than one... I have to send them all?

```
 private function __getHeaders() {
            $ns = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'; //Namespace of the WS. 
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    //Body of the Soap Header. 
            $headerbody = array('ClientIp' => $ip,
                                'CompanyId' => 1, 
                                'UserName' => 'someUser'
                                );

    //Create Soap Header.        
            $header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'InfoTag', $headerbody);
            return $header;
        }

    public function prepareWs(){
    $wsdl="the web service";
           $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => true));
    //Set the Headers of Soap Client. 
           $header = $this->__getHeaders();
           $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

I try to send this body, I inspected exception with soap fault but the message only returns "bad request NULL NULL NULL".

```
$params = new stdClass();  
      $params = new SoapVar("<tem:token>
        <bpf:type xmlns:bpf="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Bpf.Security.Common">
           <bpf1:Description xmlns:bpf1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Bpf.Security.Authentication.Common">someDesc</bpf1:Description>
           <bpf1:Id xmlns:bpf1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Bpf.Security.Authentication.Common">1</bpf1:Id>
           <bpf1:Name xmlns:bpf1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Bpf.Security.Authentication.Common">someName</bpf1:Name>
        </bpf:type>
        <bpf:password xmlns:bpf="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Bpf.Security.Common">somePass</bpf:password>
        <bpf:userName xmlns:bpf="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Bpf.Security.Common">someUser</bpf:userName>
    </tem:token>", XSD_ANYXML);

       $response = $client->Login($params);

}
```

With CURL I can send this XML and recieved the XML response too, but with SOAPClient I can't send this request.

I hope someone can help me, thanks.

This is the code I can see with firebug, the only thing I get is "bad request". When I use __getLastRequest() I see the same...
I guess the headers should not be sent correctly, however the __setSoapHeaders function returns true.
This is the output:

```
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:header>
<soap-env:contextinformation>
<item>
<key>ClientIp</key>
<value>127.0.0.1</value>
</item>
<item>
<key>CompanyId</key>
<value>1</value>
</item>
<item>
<key>UserName</key>
<value>someUser</value>
</item>
</soap-env:contextinformation>
</soap-env:header>
<soap-env:body>
<tem:login>
<tem:token>
<bpf:type>
<bpf1:description>someDesc</bpf1:description>
<bpf1:id>1</bpf1:id>
<bpf1:name>someName</bpf1:name>
</bpf:type>
<bpf:password>somePass</bpf:password>
<bpf:username>someUser</bpf:username>
</tem:token>
</tem:login>
</soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

Comment: Instead of guessing, I suggest you start to debug your problem by enabling the tracing mode of request in SoapClient and looking into which XML it generates: http://php.net/manual/soapclient.getlastrequest.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SoapHeader` treats arrays rather arbitrarily.  If you ever want to use an array, consider using [`ArrayObject` instead of the native construct](http://www.fischco.org/blog/2011/3/26/php-soapserver-objects-arrays-and-encoding.html).

However, you don't need an array at all since you're only trying to construct a single element in your header.  And because each of your internal elements (eg. **ClientIP**) has a unique namespace, you can't just pass in a basic object.  Instead, you have to specify a particular namespace for each element using the `SoapVar` class, which allows you to wrap normal PHP data in a "SOAP-ready" container that `SoapClient` can understand and translate.

```
$innerNS = "http://www.w3.org/BaufestProductivityFramework";
$outerNS = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Bpf.Common.Service";

$tag = new stdClass();
$tag->ClientIP = new SoapVar("200.125.145.10", XSD_STRING, null, null, null, $innerNS);
$tag->CompanyId = new SoapVar(1, XSD_INT, null, null, null, $innerNS);
$tag->UserName = new SoapVar("someUser", XSD_STRING, null, null, null, $innerNS);

$client->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader($outerNS, 'InfoTag', $tag));
```

Finally, as a rule, **don't manually write XML!**  Consider re-writing your SOAP body code like the header code shown here.  You ought to be able to deal specifically with the *content* of the XML, not its structure.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.. but if you see it in more detail the "InfoTag" has 2 namespaces xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" and xmlns="http://www.w3.org/BaufestProductivityFramework" this not affect my request?

Comment: The *Schema-instance* namespace does not appear to be used anywhere in the request, so I expect it's safe to omit it.

Comment: I achieved make it work but I had to override the method doRequest and manipulate the DOMDocument to make the request be identical to the original xml.
Can you help me with the body request? I really interested to make things work correctly.
Now works but.. writing xml in soapVar...
Really appreciate your help! Thanks for help me!