# Manually configuring a new WCF endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a simple WCF service:

```
namespace Vert.Host.VertService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRSVP
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool Attending();

        [OperationContract]
        bool NotAttending();
    }

    public class RSVPService : IRSVP
    {
        public RSVPService()
        {
        }

        public bool Attending()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool NotAttending()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to self-host in a console application like so:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create a ServiceHost
        using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RSVPService)))
        {
            // Open the ServiceHost to create listeners 
            // and start listening for messages.
            serviceHost.Open();

            // The service can now be accessed.
            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm using this app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>      
    <services>
      <service name="Vert.Host.VertService.RSVPService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/Vert" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint
          address="/RSVP"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="Vert.Host.VertService.IRSVP" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
              <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

As I understand it, this setup would leave me with `http://localhost:8080/Vert/RSVP/Attending` as a valid REST URI to call from an arbitrary HTTPClient, but the call is hanging indefinitely or coming back with a `0 No Response` (I'm using Advanced REST client)

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Your current WCF config is for a `basicHttpBinding` - a **SOAP** endpoint..... there's no config for a REST endpoint (that would use a `webHttpBinding`)

Comment: Do you have any good resources delineating the two? Beyond MSDN?

Comment: Go search ! Tons of good stuff out there, e.g. http://dotnetspeak.com/2012/01/creating-wcf-service-with-soaprest-endpoints or http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wcf/728/expose-wcf-service-soap-rest or answers to [this other SO question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are RIGHT in all of your setup...right up to the point where you stopped typing code and started telling me what you have.  :)

What you've created is a std WCF service and you can get to it using a Service proxy or a ChannelFactory, but it will communicate with you as-is using SOAP.

You need [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-sec) to turn this webservice into a RESTFUL service giving back Json/pox.