# Routing in WCF for Operation contracts

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I'm a beginner in WCF and have created a RESTful service called OrderProcessor with three operations:

```
bool IsClientActive(string token);
Order ProcessOrder();
string CheckStatus(Guid orderNumber);
```

I require suggestions and feedback on few points related to the same service:
1. Attribute Routing: I know that like in WebAPI, Attribute Routing is not possible in WCF, but I want to create the api with following URLs:

    `http://localhost:{portnumber}/OrderProcessor/IsClientActive/{token} - POST request for IsClientActive() method
    http://localhost:{portnumber}/OrderProcessor/ProcessOrder - GET request for the ProcessOrder() method
    http://localhost:{portnumber}/OrderProcessor/CheckStatus/{orderNumber} - POST request for the CheckStatus() method`

So, I have defined the Interface and implementation of the service as follows:

Contract - IOrderProcessor.cs

```
interface IOrderProcessor
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/api/{token}")]
    bool IsClientActive(string token);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/api")]
    Order ProcessOrder();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/api/{orderNumber}")]
    string CheckStatus(Guid orderNumber);
}
```

Implementation - OrderProcessor.cs

```
public class OrderProcessor : IOrderProcessor
    {
        public bool IsClientActive(string token)
        {
            bool status = false;
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token.Trim()))
                {
                    //Do db checking
                    status = true;
                }
                status = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception
                throw ex;
            }
            return status;
        }

        public Order ProcessOrder()
        {
            Order newOrder = new Order()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Owner = "Admin",
                Recipient = "User",
                Info = "Information about the order",
                CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
            };
            return newOrder;
        }

        public string CheckStatus(Guid orderNumber)
        {
            var status = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (!(orderNumber == Guid.Empty))
                {
                    status = "On Track";
                }
                status = "Order Number is invalid";

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Do logging
                throw;
            }

            return status;
        }
    }
```

Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCF_MSMQ_Service.OrderProcessor" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:4723/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCF_MSMQ_Service.IOrderProcessor" behaviorConfiguration="Web"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- Enable metadata publishing. -->
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />

          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  
          Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>   

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Issues:
I have implemented all the code but when i try to run it (View in Browser) using Visual Studio, I'm not able to access the above defined URLs. For example, I tried to check the URL:
http://localhost:4723/OrderProcessor/api
it is throwing the following error:

> In contract 'IOrderProcessor', there are multiple operations with
>   Method 'POST' and a UriTemplate that is equivalent to
>   '/api/{orderNumber}'. Each operation requires a unique combination of
>   UriTemplate and Method to unambiguously dispatch messages. Use
>   WebGetAttribute or WebInvokeAttribute to alter the UriTemplate and
>   Method values of an operation.

I tried to search for this error and someone suggested to put 
"[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]" on the imple,mentation class, but the error is still here [[AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher - the msg with To](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293721/addressfilter-mismatch-at-the-endpointdispatcher-the-msg-with-to]). Can someone please suggest a way to use URLs just like the WebAPI way?

Comment: So as suggested by @Mukesh Modhvadiya, I was keeping the UriTemplate same for IsClientActive() and CheckStatus() methods. The solution is to specify different names and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply UriTemplate for both your below service methods are not distinguishable,

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/api/{token}")]
bool IsClientActive(string token);
```

and

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/api/{orderNumber}")]
string CheckStatus(Guid orderNumber);
```

To distinguish you can change it as below by adding method names in UriTemplate

```
UriTemplate = "/api/isClientActive/{token}"

UriTemplate = "/api/checkStatus/{orderNumber}"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the UriTemplate similarity, I get it fixed and its working now.

Comment: @iSahilSharma, glad it helped! I appreciate your effort for adding enough information to make your question clear.