# Getting an AddressFilter Mismatch When Forwarding WCF Traffic Through an HAPRoxy Server on a Different Port

Tags: wcf

My client application makes WCF calls through an HAProxy server on port 8080 which then forwards the traffic to the application server on port 770 which is the port that the application server is expecting. However, WCF is detecting the mismatch of ports 8080 vs 770 and reports the following error:

The message with To 'net.tcp://172.31.31.219:8080/MyEndpoint' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

How can I support this scenario? Everything works fine if I update the client to send traffic on port 770, but this is a special scenario where I want to support different ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to support different ports.

Maybe you can configure multiple endpoints on the service and implement communication with each endpoint from the client, you can check out the tutorial.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/multiple-endpoints

> The message with To 'net.tcp://172.31.31.219:8080/MyEndpoint' cannot
> be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the
> EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's
> EndpointAddresses agree.

You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293721/addressfilter-mismatch-at-the-endpointdispatcher-the-msg-with-to) for the solution to this error.
If the service has only one endpoint, a quick workaround is to use

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode=AddressFilterMode.Any)]
```

This will turn off the address filter.
Or include the following in the SOAP header to access the web service:

```
<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<wsa:To>http://example.com/service</wsa:To>
</soap:title>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This service has many endpoints so I don't think I can use AddrssFilterMode.Any. Creating multiple endpoints may work. I'll look into that but it's a bit ugly. I was hoping there was some setting to tell WCF to match all of the address except for the port.

Comment: I've found that if I create a class that implements IEndpointBehavior and sets the AddressFilter to a custom MessageFilter class it seems to work. It appears the some routing occurs before it gets into this class though. I'm not sure how that happens.

Comment: You can use IDispatchMessageInspector to inspect inbound and outbound messages, you can check the documentation. [IEndpointBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) and [Custom Message Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-filter)