# PHP error when try execute .net webservice method

Tags: php, soap, methods, call

I need communicate with web-service construct in .net(i think), but when i try call a method, return this error:

> The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'http://tempuri.org/TripointWebservicesVersionedGeneral/Ping'.

Code to connect to web-service and execute method:

```
$client = new SoapClient(
                    '...?wsdl',
                        array(
                            'trace' => 1,
                            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
                        )
                    );

//$test = $client->__soapCall('Ping',array(''));
$test = $client->Ping();
```

What is the reason of this error? or what i need to do to call a method?

I have already read this [PHP Fatal error: "The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934365/php-fatal-error-the-soap-action-specified-on-the-message-does-not-match-t), and put in option of soap connection this `"'action' => '.../Ping'"` but don't help me.

Comment: In order to consume the service you need to know the structure of the function. Try to read the wsdl definition of the function you need to call.

Answer (score 1):

i've found the reason why i can't call the method's, its because of this:

One of the problems:
The PHP returns "Caught exception: Cannot process the message because the content type ‘text/xml; charset=utf-8′ was not the expected type ‘application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8′."

The reason:
WCF is running a new version of web services than expected by the PHP.

The solution:

Change the binding type of the WCF service from binding="wsHttpBinding" to binding="basicHttpBinding".

This insures that your .NET web service would support clients and other services that conform to the WS-I standards.

url source:
[http://spacebug.com/php-calling-wcf-part-1-html](http://spacebug.com/php-calling-wcf-part-1-html/)

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but I just wanted to highlight that you're probably facing this problem because you're using `SoapClient` to try and consume a web service that uses WS-Addressing.  You should try to track down what others do in this situation:

http://www.cdatazone.org/index.php?/archives/15-WS-Addressing-for-extsoap.html

https://github.com/wso2/wsf

Comment: i've tried this one, but the error persist, i'll try use nuSoap, what do you think?